# Problems without displaying content in a textarea per line

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I would like to retrieve the content of a textarea per line. So the user entered one link per line in that area.

Here is my code:

```
$links_in_textarea = get_field('links_in_textarea');

$link_trim = trim($links_in_textarea);
$link_single = explode("\n", $link_trim);
$link_single = array_filter($link_single, 'trim');

// displaying links in a list
for ($i=0; $i<=count($link_single); $i++) {
    echo "<li><a href='http://$link_single[$i]'>List Item</li>";
}
```

My problem: When I click on a list item, the link comes with the following additional string:

> %3Cbr%20/>

Anyone can see the reason for this? How do I need to modify the code above so that I can retrieve the link WITHOUT this additional string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strip_tags` to remove any html tags from it. So you will have string without any html tags.

Answer (score 1):

That's a `<br>` which is [url encoded](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php). You can eliminate it with a simple `string_replace`. This could look like this:

```
$links_in_textarea = str_replace('<br/>', '', $links_in_textarea);
```

Comment: cool, thank you. could u please suggest a line of code with which i can achieve that?

Comment: edited my answer. place this below your first line of code, to filter out all `<br>` tags.

Comment: i'm going to throw this out there... the storage function for the textarea is probably taking the raw input and converting `\n` to `<br />\n` to store it for html output, you can probably explode on that instead

Comment: He states in his question that the explode on the `"\n"` is working. So my guess would be that the storage function propably adds the `<br>` instead of replacing the `"\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment on your answer (don't have enough reputation) :
I'd suggest you run this piece of code, which is quite similar :

```
$links_in_textarea = str_replace(array('<br>', '<br />', '<br/>'), '', $links_in_textarea);
```

Feel free to read PHP's documentation about that :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#example-4915